# Why is conda not initiating shell?

Tags: bash, docker, conda, bioinformatics

I've downloaded docker on windows and tried to download a remote docker file using the code bellow.

`docker build -t bio https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PacktPublishing/Bioinformatics-with-Python-Cookbook-third-edition/main/docker/Chapter01/Dockerfile`

However, whether I run this command in the docker shell, CMD, or PowerShell. I encounter the same issue.

How can I resolve this?

[image: CMD Terminal]

Comment: Each `RUN` is a new noninteractive shell. Noninteractive shells don't source dotfiles automatically.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What would you do to get around this?

Comment: Use `conda run` instead of `conda activate`